# Page Navigation On Win Phone 8 App Load

Tags: javascript, authentication, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows 8 application for phones and created a new project using 'Navigation App' template, since I want to use a few pages in my app.

The default start page is home.html, as stated in the default.html:

```
<body class="phone">
  <div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/home/home.html'}"></div>
</body>
```

I want to check data I am saving in

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder
```

BEFORE the app is finish loading.
Depends on the data result, I want to continue to home.html or navigate to a different page.

I idea is to process everything I need in the 'splash' time and then deiced which page to load. I'm just not sure It's possible in Win Phone Development.

I though the best place for that is default.js file in onloaded event, but I have 2 problems:

- Trying to navigate from onloaded to a different page doesn't seem to work. The app always get into home.html
- Getting data is async so the app keeps loading before I got the data and able to check it.

  ```
  app.onloaded = function (args) {
  var storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

  storageFolder.getFileAsync('settings.txt').then(
      function (file) {
          if (file) {
              Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (contents) {
                  if (contents.length > 0 && contents != '{}') {
                      var settingsObj = JSON.parse(contents);
                      if ('id' in settingsObj && settingsObj.id > 0) {
                          //Go to Home

                       WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/home/home.html');
                       return;
                      }
                  }

                  //Go To Login
                  WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/login/login.html');
              });
          }
      },
      function (e) {
          storageFolder.createFileAsync('settings.txt');
      }
  );
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting that code in app.xaml.cs where the default page is normally loaded.

Check the Application data for what you are looking for then use if statements to see if the results satisfy what you want e.g

```
if(true)
{
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}else
{
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage));
}
```